# How to specify multiple locators for Selenium web element using the FindBy and PageFactory mechanisms

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I like to use `PageFactory` with `@FindBy` annotations in my automation framework to auto-locate elements in my page object classes.

I have one WebElement for which I need to be able to specify a couple of different locators. I thought FindBys was my solution, but apparently, that is not how it works. It's the equivalent of `driver.findElement(option1).findelement.(option2)`. That's not what I need. I need something that will find an element by one or the other locators. If one doesn't work, then use the other locator. Is there a way to do this in Selenium using FindBy annotations?

Comment: you'd have to do a custom solution. Extend your test cases and create your own custom PageFactory that extends PageFactory

Comment: Also, pretty much any two selectors can be combined into a single selector.  Could you explain what you are trying to find and why you need two selectors for it?

Comment: Stupid reason. There two versions of the home page hanging around in the system depending on how one navigates to it. Meanwhile my tests are failing intermittently because the element has different ids in the two versions of the page. And there is no single static item that exists in both home page versions.

Comment: So there's no flavor of FindBy type of annocations out there that allows specification of multiple locators? That would be a sweet feature because not all Webdriver implementations for different browsers can find an element using the same locator.

Comment: You can use `findby.css("[id=option1],[id=option2]")`.  The comma allows the selector to match either `id`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is apparently a new feature in Selenium as of May this year -- the @FindAll annotation that does exactly what I need;

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html
http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/Pull-Request-62-Add-a-FindAll-annotation-to-the-Java-Page-Factory-td24814.html

Comment: @FindAll can also be used for A/B testing , where we have different locator basis which version is running during automation test run.